# Ruby 2.5.1 irb: overriding + and * in Integer does not work

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm learning Ruby and want to override operators, in this case plus and multiply. What I type is:

```
class Integer
def +(other)
self - other
end
end
```

This works when I write it in a .rb file and execute it, but not on the irb shell. I'm not able to write anything after defining "+".

And when I go and redefine "*" after I restarted the irb, everything I type after that is typed twice. I am using Windows 10.

[image: Image showing what I described above]

Comment: What is the image supposed to show?

Comment: Then post your Ruby version; you may have found a bug.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with `+` in `irb` with Ruby 2.5.1.

Comment: try class Fixnum

Comment: @Phlip after you redefine `+` as described by the OP, try to do define another class with, say, `class Foo` <enter>. On Ruby 2.4.0 I get an error.

Comment: Ruby version: 2.5.0
The image just shows what I described, nothing more. There were no error messages.

Comment: @MickeySheu in my trials on 2.4.0 using `Fixnum` results in the same problem (in addition to the warning that `Fixnum` is deprecated).

Comment: @Kumpelblase edit your question and include Ruby version there. And why have the image link at all if it just shows what you described? When I click on it, it just shows a dot in the middle of the screen and the rest is black.

Comment: @MickeySheu using Fixnum says: 
"(irb):2: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
=> :+"
and again not able to write anything after that

Comment: @lurker relax, thats my first post, just trying to give as much information as possible.

Comment: Yup. When I enter the above `class Integer` etc. it works. Then when I try to start `class Fixnum` I get `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end)`, even though the `end` keywords are correct.

Comment: @lurker now that's interesting. But is this the same issue the OP is describing?

Comment: @SagarPandya It is strange. I don't see exactly the same results, but Ruby does seem to have a peculiar and different behavior depending upon which arithmetic operator I try to override.

Comment: Just updated to 2.5.1 and still have the problem.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 Version 1709